# How to add code to Header.php in a child theme?

Tags: child-theme, headers, open-graph

I'm creating a child theme for the first time and I had a few questions regarding code added to header.

In a non child theme there is certain code I add to my header.php file such as google analytics, google webmaster tools, buy sell ads, Facebook open graph, etc....

How do you do this in a child theme? Do you create a header.php file in your child theme? If so how is this done? Is it the same as the @import as I used on the css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would hook into the `wp_head` action. I would place this in a plugin so as to abstract it from your presentation layer. This allows for scalability and changing of themes. This also prevents any analytics collateral damage if a step is missed in migration from one theme to the next.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head');
function wpse_43672_wp_head(){
    //Close PHP tags 
    ?>
    ADD YOUR PLAIN HTML CODE HERE
    <?php //Open PHP tags
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any experience in making a plug in. I have about 5 pieces of code I'd like to add into the header. Would I need to make a plug in for each of them?

Comment: @RickSmith I added the plugin format to the post above

Comment: Whether using a Parent  Theme, Child Theme, or any Theme whatsoever, the *correct* approach is to put such code in a callback, hooked into the appropriate action hook. You could put this code in the Theme's `functions.php` file, or, even better and as Brian has suggested, put it in [a **site-specific Plugin**](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/).

Comment: @BrianFegter Thanks so much. Working with Php / child themes is new to me, so I"m learning as I go. Thanks for your patience. :)  In my old theme, I went into wordpress admin, than to the editor and added this to the header. <meta property="fb:page_id" content="12345678" /> Is the better way to add all of that to the plug in?

Comment: @RickSmith No problem. That's why this forum exists. :)

Comment: @BrianFegter Ok, so I just placed the above mentioned code into that plugin, and when it tries to active I get this error. What do you think I'm doing wrong? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/downsynd/public_html/wpdallas.com/test/wp-content/plugins/Ricks-Code/Rick-Widget.php on line 22

Comment: @RickSmith can you post *all* of `Rick-Widget.php` into a [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com), and link it?

Comment: @RickSmith like Chip posted, anything site specific should go in that one plugin.

Comment: @BrianFegter That pastbin expired. here is a new one. http://pastebin.com/kmmKkSDS

Comment: @RickSmith See my latest edit. Your PHP syntax is wrong. You have to use echo or close out your php tags if you want to post raw HTML in a function. `?> YOUR HTML <?php`

Comment: @BrianFegter Thanks man! I got it! That worked. One more quick question. In my old theme I had some buy sell java script that I added to the footer section of theme (I was told to do that so my theme loaded first.) Would it be ok to add that code here, or should I add it to the footer? )

Comment: You can just add another action and callback for wp_footer

Comment: @BrianFegter ok, Do you suggest putting all of this stuff in the footer? Like the google ant. webmaster tools, etc...? Not sure what the best practice is....

Comment: @RickSmith That's out of my pay grade. lol

Comment: @BrianFegter Ha,ha..thanks! :) Do you build wordpress sites?

Comment: @BrianFegter Ok, so now I'm trying to add some java script to that plug in. Going on your above example, how do I add java script to it?

Comment: Please see my latest edit. :)

Comment: if possible, can you explain what each line does?

Answer (score 7):

### Adding a Code Snippet

#### HTML

If you want to add a code snippet e.g. a meta tag etc to the `<head>`, then you should use the `wp_head` action:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head' );
function wpse_43672_wp_head() : void {
    ?>
    <meta ..... />
    <?php
}
```

There are also `admin_head` and `wp_footer`

#### Javascript & CSS

You could use the above code to also add Javascript, but instead custom JS should be enqueued as a JS file, or, included as inline JS via `wp_add_inline_script` attached to an existing enqueued JS handle.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/

This is also true of CSS, which has `wp_add_inline_style` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/

### Modifying the Sites Header

Note that once you do this, you will not see changes made in the parent theme when it updates for those files that you override and modify.

#### In A Block Theme

If your theme is a block theme then you can do this by going to the site editor and making changes in the Admin area.

#### In a Classic Theme

If your site is a classic PHP theme, then you can use a child theme.

To modify the header in a child theme, copy the file `header.php` from the parent theme into the child theme and then modify it. WordPress will see that you have a `header.php` in your child theme and use that instead of the parent theme `header.php`

Any template files you put in your child theme will take priority over the same file in the parent theme when called by WordPress.

Anything that goes in the `<head>` tag should be done using something such as the function in Brians answer. If it's theme specific, you can put it in a file called `functions.php` in your theme folder without any extra steps.

Comment: Tom, thanks. So if I need to install 5 different snips of code in the header.php, could I just make one plugin and install that? Would I still need to copy the header.php file into my child theme?

Comment: Yes there is no reason to make 5 plugins

Comment: @RickSmith If you are abstracting to a plugin, there's no reason to copy over header.php. :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when the theme is updated, you will miss out on fixes in header.php made by the author.

Comment: does WordPress override the whole file, or is it just appending new content to the parent file?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Brian Fegter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4793/brian-fegter). If this answer helps, please rate for [Brian's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43674/58130) right here above.

This is a fully functional example of how to add things to the "header" by its own plugin. In this case, I am adding the properties of Facebook Open Graph for the Share and Like buttons.

Just create a PHP file with the name specified in "Plugin Script" at the beginning of the sample code, place it in a folder with the same name without the extension, obviously, and copy this folder to the destination "/ wp-content / plugins".

Then within "Wordpress", refresh "Plugins" and you'll see your new plugin installed. Just Activate it, and your pages will begin to contain the metadata of Open Graph Facebook and Twitter.

[image]

**VERY IMPORTANT:** The PHP file must be encoded in UTF-8 without BOM, and should have absolutely no character at the end. Must ensure this.

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: My Facebook Open Graph Protocol
    Plugin Script: my-facebook-open-graph-protocol.php
    Plugin URI: 
    Description: Add Facebook Open Graph Protocol to header
    Author: Diego Soto (Thanks to Brian Fegter)
    Donate Link: 
    License: GPL    
    Version: 0.1-alpha
    Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/how-to-add-code-to-header-php-in-a-child-theme
    Text Domain: myfogp
    Domain Path: languages/
*/

/*  Copyright 2014 Diego Soto  (http://disientoconusted.blogspot.com.ar/)

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head');

function wpse_43672_wp_head(){
    $title = get_the_title() ." &lsaquo; ". get_bloginfo( "name", "display" );

    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), array( 90,55 ), false, "" ); 

    $face_metad = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "metadescription", true);

    $twitter_metad = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "metadescription140", true);
    if (empty($twitter_metad)) 
        $twitter_metad = $face_metad;

    //Close PHP tags 
    ?>    
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo esc_attr($src[0]); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php if (!empty($face_metad)) echo esc_attr($face_metad); else the_excerpt(); ?>" />

    <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo esc_attr($src[0]); ?>" />    
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php if (!empty($twitter_metad)) echo esc_attr($twitter_metad); else the_excerpt(); ?>" />
    <?php //Open PHP tags
}
?>
```

Anyone who is interested in the functionality of the plugin.

- The title will be the concatenation of the name of the current page
  and the site name.
- If a custom field called "metadescription" exists, the plugin tries
  to take the description from this field. Otherwise, take the
  description from the excerpt.
- As the image, the plugin tries to use the thumbnail of the featured
  image on the page.

Comment: Please use `esc_attr()` for the HTML attribute contents.

Comment: I modified to use esc_attr() as you told me. Thank you.