# How to hook code in <body>?

Tags: hooks

In the question [How to add code to Header.php in a child theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/43672/64282), a recommended solution is to create a plugin, then hook into `wp_head` action by using this code:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_43672_wp_head');
function wpse_43672_wp_head(){
    //Close PHP tags 
    ?>
    ADD YOUR PLAIN HTML CODE HERE
    <?php //Open PHP tags
}
```

Looking at header.php, I see that `<?php wp_head(); ?>` belongs to `<head>`, not `<body>`. So which function to use if I want to hook into the body? I don't see any `<?php wp_body(); ?>` in header.php, though I find there is `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` right before `</body>` in footer.php.

My goal is to add these code, in order to use the [Off Canvas Sidebars](https://github.com/JoryHogeveen/off-canvas-sidebars/wiki/Theme-setup) plugin:

```
<body>
    <?php do_action('website_before'); ?>
    <!-- WEBSITE CONTENT -->
    <?php do_action('website_after'); ?>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action you are looking for is `wp_body_open()`.  I do not know if you are writing your own theme or not but if you are using a pre-built theme, the author of your theme may not have included this support.

If properly supported in your theme, any function hooked to this action will be called immediately after the page opening `<body>` element.

WordPress reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_body_open/

Additional theme reference:
https://generatewp.com/wordpress-5-2-action-that-every-theme-should-use/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what action to hook CSS code?

Comment: If you are using `wp_register_script()` to register a handle for your stylesheets, the "WordPress way" to properly load the CSS is to enqueue them via a single `wp_enqueue_scripts` call like this:  `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name' );`
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#combining-enqueue-functions